# In richfaces form based error message possible?

Tags: error-handling, richfaces

I would like a catch-all display of any errors or exceptions. For instance I would like to catch 500 responses to AJAX requests and display the summary in a text field. More so I would like a single message area for the entire form (w/o specifying a separate message tag for every input or button). How can this be implemented using richfaces?

I've read the documentation located at the [richfaces demo site](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/message.jsf?c=message&tab=usage), but the 500 responses still get through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying all validation errors in your form in a single location use the `<rich:messages/>` component instead of the `<rich:message>` as shown in: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/messages.jsf

Comment: yeah, I was looking to display other exceptions gracefully, but I think I am thinking of this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As I look around I think my paradigm is wrong. I was thinking I would catch an HTML error code on return, but it looks like richfaces catches it server side and turns it into a page to display the details on the front end. I'll look into how to set up faces-config to redirect to one of my classes or maybe just create an attribute in the bean that I set to the message in a `catch` block.